# How can I get Piet Oudolf garden plans?

Tags: identification, plant-recommendations

I have inherited a farm, and behind the barn I would make a garden in the style of Piet Oudolf.

Shall I find a local gardener and show my favorit gardens him in Hummelo about this below, and ask to make one in similar style?

[image]

Or is it possible to download or buy a garden layout with the list of the flowers, and I can order the plants and build garden by myself? I checked some of his garden plans in Youtube videos, but those latin names is hard to read and for me does not have much meaning.

How would you suggest to start it?

Comment: Creating a garden on the scale you're suggesting is quite a commitment. I recommend that you consider the following before hiring a landscape designer with experience designing large gardens: 1) Design - How much money do you have for design? I would estimate a minimum of $1500 in the US 2) Plants or Seeds? Seeds are cheaper but take longer, and the garden will require weeding. If plants, what size? Larger = more money 3) Maintenance, Large gardens have staff to maintain them. Will you be the only person maintaining the garden? 4) Equipment. Do you have what you'll need to maintain the garden?

Comment: To continue... I've been assuming you want a large garden, because that's what Oudolf typically designed. His large drifts of flowers and grasses work well in them, but large drifts won't look nearly as nice in a small garden. Smaller drifts of 5 plants may work better. This will require scaling down any Oudolf plan you may find. A smaller garden, however, will be less expensive to design, less expensive to install and less expensive to maintain. Use an organic mulch like woodchips between all plants to reduce weed pressure.

Comment: Finally, designing a garden is much more complex than just planting things off of a list. An experienced designer will be more than familiar with the design concepts needed to give you a beautiful garden that has blooms throughout the spring, summer, and autumn.

Answer (score 2):

Landscape plans are unique based on the size, shape and contours of your land.  And its not cheap, but a landscape designer is the person for the job.  Sometimes the local garden center provides such a service at a more affordable price.

But if you want an exact copy then contact that garden itself and ask for information and plan.

Comment: As an experienced landscape designer at a plant nursery, I disagree with the idea that someone at a garden center or plant nursery (like myself) is an appropriate designer for such a large garden as implied by the question. I'm experienced with residential lots up to maybe a half-acre, but would be out of my depth with a such a large garden. This would be consistent with the trade, IMO. You need someone with experience designing large spaces - maybe even public gardens - to plan something that large. Cutting costs in design will lead to nothing but disappointment later.

Comment: Edit for my comment above... "half acre" should be "quarter acre".